# Solving a simultaneous (closed) stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the two following stochastic differential equations in differential/Ito form which closes onto each other such that

$$
dA_{s}(t)=\alpha A_{s}(t)dt +\beta A_{i}(t)dt+dW_{s}(t) \\
dA_{i}(t)=\alpha^{*} A_{i}(t)dt +\gamma A_{s}(t)dt+dW_{i}(t) 
$$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are constants and $dW_{s,i}$ denote Wiener increments for $A_{s}$ and $A_{i}$ respectively. How does one go about solving this? Naively, I would divide both sides of the two equations with $dt$ and form a system of non-homogenous differential equations, and proceed to solve them conventionally. But the derivative of the Wiener process is not defined. How should one approach this?

Comment: The derivative of a Wiener process is Gaussian white noise. Not a mathematically safe object but commonly used in physics. I think if you drop some rigor you can do exactly what you describe. I'd write the system in matrix form, diagonalize it, solve, then revert back to nondiagonal variables. Alternatively, you might be able to just take advantage of the fact that a linear transformation of a Gaussian process is
 Gaussian, then basically ansatz for the answer.

Comment: Your notation is not wrong but very confusing. Why don't simply denote $A(t)$, $B(t)$  instead of $A_s(t)$, $A_t(t)$ for example? Besides, this SDE has closed-form solution.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Thanks for your response. I'm hoping something with more rigor so I would prefer the full mathematical treatment. I have no problem solving it conventionally. I just want to understand the derivative of the wiener process

Comment: @NN2 Thanks for your feedback. For clarification, the subscripts $s,i$ represents signal and idler waves and $A$ is the amplitude. This is common in optics and microwave systems. Conventionally, in stochastic calculus, the time is denoted as subscript $(W_{t}=W(t))$. But since I have two different modes, I am using the subscript to denote the modes but the brackets to denote the time dependence. Hope that clears up the confusion

Comment: @NN2 Could you elaborate on how to obtain the closed form solution? Do you mean dividing $dt$ to both sides and solving it conventionally?

Comment: @NN2 correctly described basically what I outlined. If your question is "how do we interpret the derivative of a Wiener process", then you need to read about Gaussian white noise. It's the typical fundamental object of Gaussian stochastic processes in physics. In mathematics, the mathematically better-behaved Wiener process is the starting point.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the system in matrix form
$$d\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{M}\mathbf{A}dt+d\mathbf{W} \tag{1}$$
with
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} A_s(t)\\ A_i(t)  \end{pmatrix} $$
$$\mathbf{M}=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta\\ \alpha^* &\gamma   \end{pmatrix} $$
$$\mathbf{W}=\begin{pmatrix} W_s(t)\\ W_i(t)  \end{pmatrix} $$

Diagonalize $\mathbf{M}$: $\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{U}^{-1}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}$ with $\mathbf{D}$ -diagonal matrix, then
$$\begin{align}
(1)&\Longleftrightarrow d(\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{U}^{-1}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A}dt+d\mathbf{W}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow d(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A}dt+\mathbf{U}d\mathbf{W}\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow  d(\mathbf{V}) = \mathbf{D}\mathbf{V}dt+\mathbf{U}d\mathbf{W}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
with $\mathbf{V} :=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A}$

As $\mathbf{D}$  is a diagonal matrix, $(2)$ can be solved easily for $\mathbf{V}$.

*(For example, the first equation of $(2)$ will be
$$dV_1(t) = d_1 V_1(t)dt + \eta_{11} dW_s(t) +\eta_{12} dW_i(t) \tag{3}$$
and the SDE $(3)$ can be solved easily. Same for the second equation of $(2)$
)*

and so

$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U}^{-1}\mathbf{V}$$